# Reverting Patch (correct way)?

Tags: magento-1.7

One one of my Magento 1.7.0.2 installs I need to revert a 1533 patch, but original SUPEE 1533 is not available in the root folder (probably was deleted after it was installed in 2015). I am checking installed patches  in **app/etc/applied.patches.list** and it shows as SUPEE-1533_EE_**1.13**_v1.patch

However I went to magento and downloaded SUPEE-1533 to upload to Root folder and make a revert and I noticed that recently downloaded SUPEE 1533 for 1.7.0.2 is this: 
PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_**1.12**.x_v1-2015-02-10-08-19-16.sh
see difference in bold. 1.13 and 1.12.

Is it safe to upload recent PATCH_SUPEE-1533_EE_**1.12** patch and Revert it? I assume it should revert changes made by original patch "SUPEE-1533_EE_**1.13**_v1.patch  correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, SUPEE-1533_EE_1.13_v1.patch (First one, instlled in 2015) is a patch for Magento 1.8 version, but developers probably made a mistake and installed 1.8 patch version on 1.7.0.2 magento.... I checked patches for differences, both of them are the same, just different names... so essentially it doesnt matter which patch is installed.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can also check the guides from Magento itself: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_install-patches.html#apply-8788. Make sure that you install both 8788 and 1533 again.

Comment: Thanks, 1533 doesnt patch after you install 8788, they even said it in instructions.

Comment: You need v2 or v3 for that. It should work then.

Comment: after you isntall SUPEE 8788 V2 or V3, SUPEE 1533 doesnt patch because SUPEE 8788 already includes 1533 patch. thats why they asked to uninstall 1533it prior to installing supee 8788